# Progress dialog not shown on UI thread until another thread finishs

Tags: android, multithreading, progressdialog

could someone tell me why the ProgressDialog in the following code isnt displayed on the UI until after the thread completes?

```
Common.prog = ProgressDialog.show(cContext, "Please wait", "Checking Voucher...",  true);

final Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Common.prog.dismiss();
    }
};

Thread searchThread = new Thread() {  
    public void run() {
        processCoupon(voucherCodeEditText.getText().toString());
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    };
};
searchThread.run();
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try setting it up as an `AsyncTask` instead of a thread as you have it. From what I gather, that seems to be the "right" way to do something in a thread in android. Open the progressdialog in `onPreExecute()`, check voucher in `doInBackground()`, and dismiss the dialog in `onPostExecute()`

Answer (score 1):

call [start()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29) method :

```
searchThread.start();
```

run() method don't execute Runnable in new Thread.

if you want return to UI thread use [runOnUiThread()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29).